# How to trim no-break space in Java?

Tags: java, string

I've input an input file which I need to process and discard all the white-spaces, including non-breaking space `U+00A0` aka `&#160;` (You can produce it in Notepad by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then typing <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> from the keyboard's numeric pad.) or any other form of white space. I have tried [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) but it doesn't trim `U+00A0`.

Do I need to explicitly check for `U+00A0` and then `trim()` or is there an easy way to trim all kinds of white-spaces in Java?

Comment: what about `String` replace variants?

Comment: When you say "all", do you mean *all*?

Comment: yup, replace worked. :) Didn't thought of it earlier :| What is the difference between "all" & _all_?

Comment: If the question is about removing _all_ no-break spaces inside a String then the question is wrong and the accepted answer is perfect.  If the question is about trimming no_break spaces then the accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: @ForguesR Can you please explain how is the question or the answer is wrong?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

While `&#160;` is a [non breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (a space that does not want to be treated as whitespace), you can trim a string while preserving every `&#160;` within the string with a simple regex:

```
string.replaceAll("(^\\h*)|(\\h*$)","")
```

- `\h` is a horizontal whitespace character: `[ \t\xA0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000]`

If you are using a pre JDK8 Version, you need to explicitly use the list of chars instead of `\h`.

Comment: This is the cleanest and most general solution so far.  Worth mentioning that `\h` is only available since Java 8 but in earlier versions, you can use the explicit range given in your answer.

Comment: That's brilliant! Exactly a one-liner which will take care of all kinds of spaces.

Comment: One thing that might be helpful to know is that these have a Unicode Classification of Space Separator. I like this page as a reference to what's included, as the Unicode official stuff is a bit dry:

[Space Separators](http://www.fontspace.com/unicode/category/space-separator)

Comment: Why do you think `\u00A0` is not removed? Please see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). It states that this char is included in `\h` and therefore removed.

Comment: @Roland `Cfx` answered it for me :)

Comment: @Abhishek My bad, I didn't realize that `\xA0` == `'\u00A0'`.

Comment: And what about \r\n, \r and \n ? it is not escapted with your answer

Comment: Well, when \h is used for horizontal whitespace, one could guess that \v would be used for vertical whitespace ([\n\x0B\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029]). Or you would just look in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). **;-)**

Answer (score 49):

`U+0160` is not whitespace, so it won't be trimmed. But you can simply `replace()` that characters with a space, and then call `trim()`, so you keep the spaces that are 'inside' your string.

```
string = string.replace('\u00A0',' ').trim()
```

There are [three non-breaking whitespace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-) characters that are excluded from the Character.isWhitespace() method : `\u00A0`, `\u2007` and, `\u202F`, so you probably want to replace those too.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks :) I assume, I need to handle all the whitespaces (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) explicitly & one-by-one, right?

Comment: `trim()` will take care of all the characters that are listed as java whitespace, so you don't need to add all whitespace characters. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-

Comment: But this will change the "inner" NBSPs to normal spaces, might not be what you want.
"&nbsp foo&nbsp35 nbsp" will become "foo 35" not "foo&nbsp" which would be expected of trim.

Comment: @ViktorMellgren yes, but OP asked for: I've input an input file which I need to process and *discard all the white-spaces*

Answer (score 15):

You can try this:

```
string.replaceAll("\\p{Z}","");
```

From https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html:

> \p{Z} or \p{Separator}: any kind of whitespace or invisible separator.

Answer (score 5):

If you happen to use [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) then you can use [strip](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#strip-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and add all the characters you want.

```
final String STRIPPED_CHARS = " \t\u00A0\u1680\u180e\u2000\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000";

String s = "\u3000 \tThis str contains a non-breaking\u00A0space and a\ttab. ";
s = StringUtils.strip(s, STRIPPED_CHARS);  
System.out.println(s);  // Gives : "This str contains a non-breaking space and a    tab."
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with a guava [`CharMatcher`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.guava/guava/26.0-jre/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html), for example:

```
CharMatcher.anyOf("\r\n\t \u00A0").trimFrom(input);
CharMatcher.whitespace().trimFrom(input);
```

See also this [nice reference on whitespaces definition](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pd8dAQyHbdewRsnE5x5GzKQ)

Comment: There are far more whitespace characters that you have put in your list.

Comment: The link to whitespace definition is dead.

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind the [`string.trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) method is more or less the following (it does not use `charAt`, but the internal `byte[]` that stores the characters):

```
public String trim(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }
    int originalLength = s.length();
    int start = 0;
    int end = originalLength;
    while (start < end && isTrimmable(s.charAt(start))) {
        start++;
    }
    while (start < end && isTrimmable(s.charAt(end-1))) {
        end--;
    }
    return ((start > 0) || (end < originalLength)) ? s.substring(start, end) : s;
}
```

where `isTrimmable` means less or equal `'\u0020'`. You can implement an util method with custom logic to detect trimmable characters without using a regex:

```
public static String fullTrim(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }
    int originalLength = s.length();
    int start = 0;
    int end = originalLength;
    while (start < end && isTrimmable(s.charAt(start))) {
        start++;
    }
    while (start < end && isTrimmable(s.charAt(end-1))) {
        end--;
    }
    return ((start > 0) || (end < originalLength)) ? s.substring(start, end) : s;
}

public static boolean isTrimmable(char c) {
    return Character.isWhitespace(c) || c == '\u00A0' || c == '\u2007' || c == '\u202F';
}
```

This is a solution that doesn't use a regex or the (equivalent) [StringUtils.strip(string, charactersToStrip)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#strip-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), as I prefer to maintain a `isTrimmable` method than a `charactersToStrip`/regex string.