# android splitting with space not working for this case. Why?

Tags: java, android, split

I need to highlight and make url in the text clickable, dynamically.

For that, I am using the below method

```
private SpannableString addClickablePart(String string) {


        string = string.replaceAll("\\n"," \n ");

        string += " ";
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(string);
        String[] words = string.split(" ");
        for (final String word : words) {


            if (CommonUtilities.isValidURL(word)) {


                int lastIndex = 0;

                while(lastIndex != -1){

                    lastIndex = string.indexOf(word+" ",lastIndex);

                    if(lastIndex != -1){
                        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View textView) {
                                //use word here to make a decision

                                isRefreshingNecessary = false;

                                Intent mIntent = new Intent(ctx, UserWebsiteActivity.class);
                                mIntent.putExtra("website", word);
                                startActivity(mIntent);
                            }
                        };

                        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, lastIndex, lastIndex + word.length(),
                                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                        lastIndex += word.length();
                    }
                }


            }
        }

        return ss;
    }
```

Its working for most of the cases. But, not working for all the cases as the below example.

> The pricing information provided to you in your plan terms and
>   conditions about these number ranges will no longer apply and will be
>   replaced by this charging structure. See www.ee.co.uk/ukcalling for
>   further information.

As, for the above case, when I split the whole string using

```
 String[] words = string.split(" ");
```

or

```
 String[] words = string.split("\\s+");
```

I got `See www.ee.co.uk/ukcalling for` as a single word. Instead, I need these 3 - `See`,`www.ee.co.uk/ukcalling` and `for` as 3 different words, not to be as grouped as a single word.

I am unable to understand whats wrong in the way of splitting with space.
Please help me to know.

Comment: Why downvoting? I mentioned what I tried. Please let me know whats wrong, so that, I can improve, instead of just downvoting.

Comment: you can also assign them to 3 different textviews for simplicity

Comment: I have dynamic strings so, I cannot deal them in static way. I will have only single textview, in which need to highlight the url parts, wherever exists @VivekMishra

Comment: The **most likely** reason for the downvote is because it's not reproducible... Can you reproduce the issue in ideone.com and share the link?

Comment: let me check that link, please.

Comment: How does this work? Do you get any true here for that string?  CommonUtilities.isValidURL(word)

Comment: yes, exactly. @sgpalit. But, I checked, the problem is in split part.

Comment: string = string.replaceAll("\\n"," \n "); instead of this can you try string = string.replaceAll("\\n"," \\n "); does this matter?

Comment: not sure, but let me check if it works @sgpalit

Comment: @Codebender I tried the same code with same text at the link you mentioned - http://ideone.com/hbmrCb.
But, strangely, its working fine at this link. But, the same thing is not working in my code.
I tested using  System.out.println(word);
In my code, I am getting like - **See www.ee.co.uk/ukcalling for**

but seems okay in the link. What may be the reason?

Comment: Do you have any not visible html characters like &nbsp; between these words?

Comment: @sgpalit don't know, I am getting this from server and it shows space, and also its showing me space in my log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace all non visible white space characters.

```
 string = string.replaceAll("\\t", " ");
 string = string.replaceAll("\\xA0", " ");
 string = string.replaceAll("\\u1680", " ");
 string = string.replaceAll("\\u180e", " ");
 string = string.replaceAll("\\u2000", " ");
 string = string.replaceAll("\\u200a", " ");
 string = string.replaceAll("\\u202f", " ");
 string = string.replaceAll("\\u205f", " ");
 string = string.replaceAll("\\u3000", " ");
```

for java 8

```
string = string.replaceAll("(^\\h*)|(\\h*$)","");
```

check this [how-to-trim-no-break-space-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295504/how-to-trim-no-break-space-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

Try like this. it works in all cases For me

```
 SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Your String");
  ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
  @Override
   public void onClick(View textView) {
    //Perform Click Here
   }
@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    super.updateDrawState(ds);
    ds.setUnderlineText(false);
}
};

ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, pos, last+5, Spanned.SPAN_USER);


    desc.setText(ss);
    desc.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    desc.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Please Note desc is my TextView to whom i set String. 
Thanks.Hope It Helps